# How to determine which value in IN clause that was matched

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database that I want to query for multiple values at the same time (for prestanda purposes). I would like to send in an IN-clause and get a list of the matched rows and their equivalent IN-clause value in return. To that I want to preserve the order in the IN-Clause

**Query-template:**

```
select id 
    from mytable
    where id in (select id from myalias where alias in ('alias a', 'alias b')
    and name = 'name 1' or name = 'name 2' ;
```

How do I know which row (id) in the results is for 'name 1' and 'name 2' respectively?

Is this possible to achieve without too much hustle?

**resulting table:**

```
id | alias
-----------
2  | alias a
1  | alias b
```

Note:  if IN-clause order is maintained in results table, the alias column can be omitted

**myalias:**

```
id | alias
-------------
1  | alias b
1  | alias d
2  | alias a
3  | alias z
```

**myTable:**

```
id | name
-----------
1  | name 1
2  | name 2
3  | name 2
```

Comment: Select MyOtherValue, MyValue...  Should do it no?

Comment: As additional to @JoeC 's suggest, use `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` claues.

Comment: @FredrickGauss, how come you suggest SELECT DISTINCT, and ORDER BY?

Comment: made an edit that i think clearifies the question. THe first example looked too simple at first sight.

Comment: @jarlh: he changed the question and resultset template.
@Fontanka16: why dont you use `*` which brings all columns then rule out unwanted ones?

Comment: the order of the value in the IN-clause is important to me to keep. So i need to be sure that it is kept.

Comment: You should include sample data and output, otherwise I am not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: Please change database schema as well as column names to more understandable ones. It does not only confuse you but also blows out our minds.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT myValue, v.val
FROM myTable t LEFT JOIN
     (VALUES ('o1'), ('o2'), ('o3'), ('o4')) v(val)
     ON t.myOtherValue = v.val;
```

It strikes me that you can also just do:

```
SELECT myValue, 
       (CASE WHEN myOtherValue IN ('o1', 'o2', 'o3', 'o4')
             THEN myOtherValue
        END) as val
FROM myTable t;
```

The matched value is already there in `myOtherValue`.

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is correct on the first query?  That 2nd left join looks troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?  Adding name to the select list lets you know which name matches which id.  The join takes the place of the where in...

```
select name, id 
    from mytable m
    join (select id from myalias where alias in ('alias a', 'alias b') a on m.id = a.id
    where name = 'name 1' or name = 'name 2' ;
```

Comment: I do not think the order of the values in the IN-clause is kept this way.